# Connect html form with models in django to submit data

Tags: html, django

I want to know how to connect the below html form with a specific model. Also how can I connect multiple forms to multiple models ( or rather tables in the database) to submit data.

## html

```
<form action='register' method="POST" >
                {% csrf_token %}
             
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="name">NAME :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="first_name" name="name" maxlength="50" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="email">EMAIL :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email"  placeholder="This will be your User ID"></td>
                    </tr>
                   
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="phone">MOBILE NUMBER :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" ></td>
                    </tr>
                          
                     <tr>
                        <td><label for="join_as">JOIN AS :</label></td>
                        <td><select id="join_as" name="join_as" >
                            <option value="select" disabled selected hidden>Select...</option>
                            <option value="individual" >INDIVIDUAL</option>
                            <option value="firm" >FIRM</option>
                            <option value="company" >COMPANY</option>
                            <option value="consultancy">CONSULTANCY</option>
                            <option value="students" >STUDENTS</option>
                            <option value="others" >OTHERS</option>
                        </td>
                        </select>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="passpwrd">PASSWORD:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="10" placeholder="max 10 characters" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="con_passpwrd">CONFIRM PASSWORD :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" id="con_password" name="con_password" maxlength="10" ></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

</form>
```

## model.py

```
    class Regd3(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username= models.EmailField(max_length=254, primary_key= True)  #email
    mobile_number= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    password= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    agreed= models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**what shall i write in views.py or how to submit data exactly?**

Comment: Try using [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

Comment: Ok I'll try, thank you. But this will throw its own form right, I want to connect the existing html form with that